# Is there a way to Syntax Highlight on Discord.js but also put in a function call?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make something like this;

[image: Shows the statistics but is syntax highlighted]

but my issue is when I'm in my code, I can't call the statistics from the API and put it into a syntax highlight.

[[image: It is put into syntax highlight, but will not pull the needed information from the api.2]

My embed's code is

```js
.addField(
    {
        name: [${player.stats.bedwars.level}✫] ${player.rank} ${player}`,
        value: "`Note: If ${player}'s WS is 0, their API may be off.`"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You're supposed to use the template literals properly.

```js
.addFields([
   {
      name: `[${player.stats.bedwars.level}✫] ${player.rank} ${player}`,
      value: `\`Note: If ${player}'s WS is 0, their API may be off.\``
   }
])
```

- You need to use [`addFields()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) for an array of fields, OR
- You could use `.addField()` with only 2 parameters and you're job is done!

```js
.addField(`[${player.stats.bedwars.level}✫] ${player.rank} ${player}`, `\`Note: If ${player}'s WS is 0, their API may be off.\``)
```

- Using a backslash (`\`) will help you use template literals inside template literals.